# How to get actual datatype using ResultSet object?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, resultset

I am using java's ResultSetMetaData.getColumnTypeName() method to find the resultset datatype of the dynamically constructed query. But for the below query

> Select Adddate('2013-12-10',10) // MySQL Query

It return "Char". Why it so?? I expect Date.

Experts please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that actually gets the column type?

Comment: <code> public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection cx = getConnection();
        Statement st = cx.createStatement();
 String sql="Select Adddate('2013-12-10',10)";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        String type = rsMetaData.getColumnTypeName(1);
        System.out.println("Data Type: "+type);
} </code> @peter

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast your result to DATE:

```
SELECT CAST(ADDDATE('2013-12-10',10) as DATE);
```

I think ADDDATE behaves just like DATE_ADD, which returns string in this case:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: If I pass actual date datatype column as an argument(Say Adddate(Salesdate,10), It returns "Date". But If I pass actual date value('2013-12-10') then only it returns "Char". The query is dynamically generated in a different system. I don't have any official privileges to modify the query. Without modifying query is there any way to find the above query return type is "Date" datatype?.

Comment: No, there's no other way, since the returned type is indeed *Char*.